# Como puedo agrupar por defecto en odoo?

Tags: python, xml, filtro, odoo, group-by

Necesito agrupar por defecto una serie de facturas (por años) y tengo esta vista heredada ya dada:

```
        <record id="view_account_invoice_filter_globalatac" model="ir.ui.view">
        <field name="name">account.invoice.filter.globalatac</field>
        <field name="model">account.invoice</field>
        <field name="inherit_id" ref="account.view_account_invoice_filter"/>
        <field name="arch" type="xml">
            <group position="inside">
                <filter name="date_invoice_year" string="Año" context="{'group_by':'date_invoice:year'}"/>
            </group>
        </field>
    </record>
```

He visto por ahí que se puede añadir el context por defecto al action pero no me aparece y no se si tengo que crearlo

```
<field name="context">{'group_default_date_invoice_year': 1}</field>
```

Estoy intentando heredar tambien la vista para añadir el context nuevo pero no se que poner en el name del field:

```
<record model="ir.ui.view" id="view_account_invoice_filter_override">
        <field name="name">account.invoice.tree</field>
        <field name="model">account.invoice</field>
        <field name="inherit_id" ref="account.invoice_tree"/>
        <field name="arch" type="xml">
            <field name="aqui no se que poner" position="attributes">
                <attribute name="context">{"search_default_date_invoice_year":1}</attribute>
            </field>
        </field>
    </record>
```

Comment: ¿Puedes traducir tu pregunta?

Comment: Basicamente tengo que añadir de alguna manera ese context para que al abrir x apartado del odoo este agrupado por defecto con el valor que yo le de, que en este caso seria agrupado por año

Comment: Buenas esto es SO español por lo tanto las preguntas deben estar en español, si lo deseas tienes también [SO](https://stackoverflow.com) en inglés. Por lo tanto te recomendaría o borrar la pregunta y preguntar allí, o bien traducirla. Un saludo y bienvenido!

Comment: @Lleims Permíteme una pequeña corrección a tu comentario: Es *SO en español*, no *España*. Pero tienes razón en lo que expones :D

Comment: perdonadme, ya esta actualizado

Comment: @PabloLozano a los pocos minutos me he dado cuenta y lo he corregido, pensé que con suerte nadie lo habría visto jajajaja